# Creating the proper axis labels and understanding them

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

I had to create a contour graph (in python) based on a formula and several other parameters. My graph came out fine. However, my axis labels will not show. I have tried changing the code several times but I am actually a little lost as how to what my real problem is. I know it deals with the command to create the labels but understand the error message

Also, this is my first post and if you have recommendations for how I should ask questions, I would appreciate the help.

```
def contourf_plot():
    T = np.linspace(0,30,50)
    P = np.linspace(600,1000,50)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(T,P) 
    Z = (Y/100)*np.e**((12*X)/(X+243))
    Z.shape
    plt.figure()
    CF = plt.contourf(T,P,Z,50)
    plt.colorbar(CF)
    plt.set_Tlabel("Temperature[$\degree$C]")
    plt.set_Plabel("Pressure[Pa]")
    plt.show()
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    contourf_plot()
```

Error message: `'module' object has no attribute 'set_Xlabel'`

Comment: I am sorry about the code posting that way, I didn't think it would

Comment: Are `set_Tlabel` and `set_Plabel` really methods?  Where did you hear about them?  Are you sure the error wasn't `'module' object has no attribute 'set_Tlabel'` ?

Comment: Did the answer below fix your issue? If so please accept the answer, if not then comment what further issues you are having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is a slight change in your code. You are currently trying to add a label to the axes T and P, though they do not exist (it is still the x and y axes). T and P are just the data that you are trying to plot.

```
def contourf_plot():
    T = np.linspace(0,30,50)
    P = np.linspace(600,1000,50)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(T,P)
    Z = (Y/100)*np.e**((12*X)/(X+243))
    Z.shape
    fig,ax = plt.subplots()  #add this line
    CF = plt.contourf(T,P,Z,50)
    plt.colorbar(CF)
    ax.set_xlabel("Temperature[$\degree$C]")  #sets the x and y label
    ax.set_ylabel("Pressure[Pa]")
    plt.show()
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    contourf_plot()
```

This gives the image

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your assistance. This indeed solved my problem and I have a better understanding now of the problem.